# Ruby Program/Problem

Tags: ruby

Given a string of characters as input, without using regular expression or pattern matching, how to get the output, if the characters matches aaa should output 1 and if the characters matches aBa should output 2. (Note: Should not re-process characters so as to output both “1” and “2” when processing the same input)

So for example:

given 'aaBaBaaaBaaa' it should output 211

given 'aaaBaBaaaaBBaBaBa' it should output 1212

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unable to figure how how your output maps to your input, need a better description of the problem.  What does aaaaaaaa yield, a single "1"?

Comment: @meagar: As I read it, the patterns can't overlap.  So "aaaaaaaa" would parse as "[aaa][aaa]aa", yielding "11"

Comment: What happens if two patterns match? Such as you were given the patterns "aaa" and "aaaa"?

Comment: This sounds very much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018244/how-to-replace-a-string-between-two-substrings-in-a-string-in-vc-mfc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without using regular expression or pattern matching

```
#input = 'aaBaBaaaBaaa'
input = 'aaaBaBaaaaBBaBaBa'
codes = {'aaa' => 1, 'aBa' => 2}
patterns = codes.keys
output = []

current = 0
length = input.length

while current <= length - 1
    is_find = false
    patterns.each do|pattern|
        len = pattern.length
        if input[current, len] == pattern
            output << codes[pattern]
            current += len
            is_find = true
            break
        end
    end

    current += 1 if !is_find
end

p output
```

Comment: p output.join - he wanted a string ;)  Nicely done though, solved the problem and then added the flexibility of adding new "codes" of any length.

Comment: Excellent. How about the same in JAVA?

Comment: The algorithm is pretty solid, so the solution in Java is pretty much the same. Biggest changes are you lose access to Ruby's each iterator, and hashes aren't part of the default types. There are many ways around that. For starters, you could import java.util.HashMap, or you could redefine the codes hash as an array of code objects.

Comment: After reviewing the code again, and the given conditions of not using regular expression or pattern matching, I believe although the solution is good it doesn't satisfy all the conditions. Isn't (if input[current, len] == pattern) considered as pattern matching?

Comment: @satynos It is only pattern matching only if you also consider, if "Hello" == "Hello" to also be pattern matching. And if you do, then your requirements can't be satisfied.

Comment: `pattern` is just a variable name. Substitute `code` or `str` if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want a state machine:

```
require 'statemachine'

state_machine = Statemachine.build do
  trans :_, :a, :a
  trans :_, :B, :_
  trans :a, :a, :aa
  trans :a, :B, :aB
  trans :aa, :a, :_, 'print 1'
  trans :aa, :B, :aB
  trans :aB, :a, :_, 'print 2'
  trans :aB, :B, :_
end

"aaBaBaaaBaaa".each_char do |i|
  state_machine.process_event(i)
end

state_machine.reset
puts

"aaaBaBaaaaBBaBaBa".each_char do |i|
  state_machine.process_event(i)
end
```